# Div disappears when window resize

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a small animation of two circles for the web, and I want it to be responsive so when I make the window "phone size" everything will still be there.

Each circle is a div, and both of them are inside a div with the class animation container. Everything changes sizes and is shown on the screen except the circles.

I have tried resizing them to see if they were too big, but it hasn't worked. I don't know what to do, help, please. We are using react and some bootstrap, but I think it has to do more with the CSS.

JSX Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Container, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import useAuth from './useAuth'
import TrackSearchResult from './TrackSearchResult'
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node'
import Player from './Player'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import './Dashboard.css'
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: '0d9e02c2d8504b05a8ae26f33b338212',
});

export default function Dashboard({code}) {
    const accessToken = useAuth(code)
    const [search,setSearch] = useState('')
    const [searchResults,setSearchResults] = useState([])
    const [playingTrack, setPlayingTrack] = useState()

    function chooseTrack(track) {
        setPlayingTrack(track)
        //we clear the search when we choose a track
        setSearch('')
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!accessToken) return
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken)
    },[accessToken])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!search) return setSearchResults([])
        if (!accessToken) return

        let cancel = false //so we just search on request at a time
        spotifyApi.searchTracks(search)
        .then(res => {
            if (cancel) return
            setSearchResults(res.body.tracks.items.map(track => {
                //loop through all images and get the smallest image
                const smallestAlbumImage = track.album.images.reduce((smallest, image) => {
                    if (image.height < smallest.height) {
                        return image
                    } else {
                        return smallest
                    }
                }, track.album.images[0])

                return {
                    artist: track.artists[0].name,
                    title: track.name,
                    uri: track.uri,
                    albumUrl: smallestAlbumImage.url
                }
            }))
        })
        return () => cancel = true
    },[search, accessToken])

    return (
    <Container className="d-flex flex-column pt-2 pb-0 px-0" style={{height:"100vh"}}>
        {/* <Form.Control 
        type="search" 
        placeholder="Search Songs/Artists" 
        value={search} 
        onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} //to get the value of search
        /> */}
        <div className="animation-container align-items-center">
            <div
            id="shape-1"
            class="
                    rounded-circle
                    position-absolute
                    opacity-70
                    scale-up-center
                    d-none d-md-block
                    "
            ></div>
            <div
            id="shape-2"
            class="
                    rounded-circle
                    position-absolute
                    opacity-70
                    scale-up-center
                    fade-delay-2000
                    d-none d-md-block
                    "
            ></div>
        </div>
        <div className="song-container">
            <div className="song">song1</div>
            <div className="song">song2</div>
            <div className="song">song3</div>
            <div className="song">song4</div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-grow-1 my-2" style={{overflowY: "auto"}}>
            {/* VERY IMPORTANT
            Here we use track arrow function with parentesis and not curly brackets
            maybe because it returns a component */}
            {searchResults.map(track =>(
                <TrackSearchResult track={track} key={track.uri} chooseTrack={chooseTrack}/>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div><Player accessToken={accessToken} trackUri={playingTrack?.uri}/></div>
        <Navbar/>
    </Container>
    )
}
```

CSS:

```
.animation-container {
    height: 50vh;
    max-width: 20vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#shape-1,
#shape-2,
{
    min-width: 25vh;
    height: 25vh;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    filter: blur(24px);

}

#shape-1 {
    background-color: hsl(225, 100%, 43%);
    left: 99vh;
}

#shape-2 {
    background-color: hsl(0, 92%, 64%);
    right: 99vh;
}


.scale-up-center {
    animation: scale-up-center 7s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) infinite both;
}

@keyframes scale-up-center {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
    }

    33% {
        transform: translate(30px, -50px) scale(1.1);
    }

    66% {
        transform: translate(-20px, 20px) scale(0.9);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
    }
}

.fade-delay-2000 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

.fade-delay-4000 {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.song-container {
    padding: 3em;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2em;
    height: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.song {
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: .3em;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 10vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the direct sandbox link for this. It be easy to check this.

Comment: @RajatJain how do i create one?

Comment: You can go to http://jsfiddle.net/ to create one. There are few other platforms similar to this.